# Mysql runs the code,but only the first table is created

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm developing an app and using JavaMysql to connect to the database. As the title states, the 2nd table (autochans) is not creating.

I've tried running both SQL connects in one statement but also failed

This is how i connect to the db, using  java.sql.*;

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.host + ":" + this.port + "/" + this.database, this.user, this.password);
```

The main code

```
public MySql initialize() {

    connect();

    try {
        connection.prepareStatement("SELECT 1 FROM guilds LIMIT 1").executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            connection.prepareStatement(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (\n" +
                            "  `id` text,\n" +
                            "  `prefix` text,\n" +
                            "  `joinmsg` text,\n" +
                            "  `leavemsg` text,\n" +
                            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"

            ).execute();

            connection.prepareStatement(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `autochans` (\n" +
                            "  `chan` text,\n" +
                            "  `guild` text,\n" +
                            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"
            ).execute();

            System.out.println("MySql structure created...");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolons at the end of the statement.  You need those only when using the mysql CLI.

Comment: Don't you mean by the end of the ```CHARSET=utf8;``` if yes,still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the comma for the last column.

Try with

```
        connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (\n" +
                        "  `id` text,\n" +
                        "  `prefix` text,\n" +
                        "  `joinmsg` text,\n" +
                        "  `leavemsg` text\n" +
                        ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"

        ).execute();

        connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `autochans` (\n" +
                        "  `chan` text,\n" +
                        "  `guild` text\n" +
                        ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
        ).execute();
```

Comment: You can always validate your sql queries here
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/